# PostgreSQL sockets from JavaScript (HTML5)

Tags: javascript, sockets, postgresql, html, node.js

I'm looking at options to connect directly--without a web server or middleware--to a PostgreSQL server using JavaScript from a web browser client.  On github, I found three projects:

1. [node_postgres](https://github.com/ry/node_postgres)
2. [node-postgres](https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres)
3. [postgres-js](https://github.com/creationix/postgres-js)

They all appear to be in early but at least somewhat active development.

Do they all do roughly the same thing?  Is what they do even what I'm looking for?  Does anyone have experience with any of them that could recommend one over the others?

Comment: @Kev - not quite sure is it a good idea. Placing database connection information in server require you to protect single computer only, but how to protect users PC NOT to be hijack by somebody ?

Comment: @ajreal, isn't that true no matter how many layers there are?  If you have well-defined database roles and privileges, it shouldn't be a problem.  (Especially for an intranet app, say.)  Don't tell me you're assuming the single-superuser-account strategy... :)

Comment: @Kev - It not about user-per-account privileges, the idea probably encourage expose more information to client side. Beside this, wondering the network travel between client->database is comparable to server->database, potentially database unable to release resource sooner ?

Comment: @ajreal, what more information?  Server version, etc?  You have that at whatever public-facing layer you're left with in the end.  Yes, network travel may be comparable, but that's not the only factor.  I'm not sure what you mean about the database being unable to release resources sooner--do you mean connections?  That's not the end of the world.  You could have a pgAgent job ditch any connections that have been idle for longer than a certain time, and have your client side handle that gracefully, only reconnecting when once again required.

Comment: @Kev - If you permit the connection between server and database only, at least you don't spread information all over the place. And now you trying to permit between database and user PC? For the connection resource, you can ditch any connections as you mentioned, what if the clients located very far, and it's not able to sent response back to server just in time, so would you end up keep ditch the so-called idle connection?

Comment: @ajreal, I'm still not sure what more information you're talking about, because you can only get information from the server with a valid login.  You know, it's just the old client-server architecture but with a web browser as the client.  As for far-away connections, so what?  Then they reconnect.  It's still less overhead, no?

Comment: @Kev - You are trying to transmit connection information I would think is need to protected from being viewable by public. And what if the re-connect keep failings ? Less overhead ? NO, you just create more overhead by letting database kept the result/connection without release it (like far-away network). Why I said so? If you connect database in your server, fetch the results, and release the database result. Via client's socket, I not sure...

Comment: @ajreal, hence PostgreSQL's SSL support: http://developer.postgresql.org/pgdocs/postgres/protocol-flow.html#AEN87263 .  As for repeated failings, I'm still not convinced.  In a 3-tier setup, you have an HTTP request every time.  So if in this setup you only have a reconnection every time *if* they're far away, but otherwise have less reconnection, it's a net improvement, I would think.  Again, it's just client-server, like, say, how xTuple works, but instead of a platform-specific binary you're running JS in a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

node-postgres was [inspired by](http://groups.google.com/group/nodejs/browse_thread/thread/f800794c674387ac?tvc=2) postgres-js and does roughly the same thing.

However, they both seem to be their own sort of middleware, because they require node.js, which is a server-side JavaScript implementation of a web server.  So they would cut out a layer, but still not be the same thing as connecting directly to the PostgreSQL server.

There might be a way to combine the code in them with some HTML5 socket examples, though, to make connections directly from a web browser client.

Comment: postgres-js is less actively maintained.

Comment: I was thinking of doing what you are asking - did you manage to make connections directly to postgres? I think a tuned postgres could double as your HTTP server! :)

Comment: It's less doable than we think.  Sockets and WebSockets are two different beasts, apparently.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188825/porting-node-js-server-side-code-to-html5-websockets for more information.  I think probably the closest we could get (unless you want to compile a web server into postgres somehow...) is either running wsproxy on the server and a converted node-postgres on the client, running Apache with mod_libpq ( http://asmith.id.au/mod_libpq.html ) (either recompiling for win32 or switching to Linux), or just running node.js with node-postgres.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in CLIENT side JavaScript, as the OP's question implied, but you don't insist on owning the server, there is a commercial service that can help you.

The Rdbhost service makes PostgreSQL servers accessible from client-side JavaScript.  There is a security system to prevent unauthorized queries, using a server-side white-list and an automated white-list populating system.

It uses plain old AJAX style http requests, provides a jQuery extension to facilitate the querying.

See https://www.rdbhost.com .

Comment: Interesting, but I don't think they are giving you direct access to the db server.  It still goes through middleware, AFAICT.

Answer (score 0):

There is no secure solution today. One of possible solutions would be htsql:
http://htsql.org/

However there you use web addresses to query, even with https your queries will be plain text!

You should/could use a small webserver to handle requests. Alternativelly you can write an app, or use a local postgres server to handle the connection (in this case you still will need some kind of webserver).

The problem is very simple: your webbrowsers are limited in protocols to talk to the web, and postgres is not on this list. In fact you should not try to overcome this issue, using a server-client architecture is a very good solution. Format your request with JS to make it as small as possible, and let your web-server scripts interpret it into functional sql requests. The answer can be parsed into shorter response, then a sql data transfer, and you just need to interpret it on your side. Since you will create interperers on all sides, you will achieve a higher abstraction then in case of direct db connection, and thus independency towards the backend engines you use.